# Vulkan: Struggeling with image layouts in multisubpass renderpasses

Tags: c++, rendering, vulkan

### Context:

As an example take a deferred renderer.

It might have this list of image attachments

```
0: depth
1: swapchain
2: position
3: normal
4: albedo
5: resolve
```

And the following subpasses that are defined with a binding and list of attachments used by them:

```
0: [0, 2, 3, 4]
1: [0, 5]
2: [0, 1]
```

With this setup images `2, 3, 4` would need to habe be in the `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL` for the first layout and then be transitioned to `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL` to be used in the second subpass.

I understand that this can be done through the usage of `VkSubpassDependency` and implicit layout transition. I also understand `VkAttachmentReference::layout` in the `VkSubpassDescription::pColorAttachments` is the desired layout for that subpass.

How do i create the `VkSubpassDescription` to reflect this?

### Attempt:

My current attempt in pseudo code

```
descriptions := vector<VkSubpassDescription>

for each subpass in subpasses {
  references:= std::vector<VkAttachmentReference>

  depth_attachment := optional<int>

  for each attachment in image_attachments {
    if attachment is depth:
      depth_attachment = attachment.binding
      continue
    }

    reference := VkAttachmentReference
    reference.attachment = attachment.binding
    reference.layout = contains(subpass.attachments, attachment) ? VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL : VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL

    references.push_back(reference)
  }

  descriptions.push_back(create_description(VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, references, depth_attachment)
}
```

Where `create_description` creates a `VkSubpassDescription` and optionally fills out the `VkSubpassDescription::pDepthStencilAttachment`

### Problem:

The problem with this setup is, that attachments that are not used in the first subpass conflict with `VkAttachmentDescription::loadOp` of `VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR` since they are in `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL` and can not be written to.

### Question:

Do I get the core concepts correct and am I going in the right direction with this approach to renderpasses with multiple subpasses?

### EDIT:

I have read about `VkSubpassDescription::pInputAttachments` and they might help with some of the problem. But wont be usefull when I want to add another subpass that handles e.g. post processing effects since input attachments can only be queried at the furrent fragments `x, y, layer`

Comment: "*attachments that are not used in the first subpass conflict with VkAttachmentDescription::loadOp of VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR since they are in VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL and can not be written to.*" No, they're not. The attachments you don't use in the first subpass are just 1 and 5. Neither of which should be in the read-only layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have read about `VkSubpassDescription::pInputAttachments` and they might help with some of the problem. But wont be usefull when I want to add another subpass that handles e.g. post processing effects since input attachments can only be queried at the furrent fragments `x, y, layer`

This is your problem.

For the duration of a render pass instance, image subresources used as attachments can *only* be access *as attachments*. If you want to write to them as shader outputs, you must use them in a subpass as a color or depth/stencil attachment. If you want to read from them in a shader, you *must* use them as input attachments.

You cannot arbitrarily read from an image subresource that is an attachment of the current render pass instance.

If you want to read an image you've written arbitrarily (ie: not just from the current fragment's position), you have to *break* the render pass. That is, you need to end the render pass and start a new one, where that image is no longer an attachment. And you need to use all of the appropriate dependencies in place between the two render passes.

For deferred rendering, input attachments are really useful and you ought to use them. Your setup needs to change. Subpass 1 needs to use attachments 2-4 as input attachments (also, reconstruct the position from the depth buffer rather than storing it in a big texture).

But if you're doing post-processing that needs to read arbitrarily from the color buffer, you need a new render pass.